# Create paperjs objects detached from PaperScope

Tags: paperjs

I am hoping it is possible to create, say, a `Paper.Path` object that is *not attached to a scope*. The reason I need to do this is because I have a few parser classes who's job it is to generate geometry from a gerber file, they should not have any influence over the `PaperScope`'s `canvas`. A simple separation of concerns.

For example: (this code won't work)

```
import paper, {Path, Point} from 'paperjs';

let path = new Path([new Point(100, 100), new Point(200, -50)]);

paper.addPath(path); <- this doesn't exist but you get the point.
```

There are no obvious ways to go about this, and the paperjs docs seem to tout this "clever scoping" as a feature, but it's really been a pain to work with...

Comment: If you remove a path just after you create it (`path.remove()`), it won't be drawn on any canvas (but you can still work with it as you want). Would that work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup Paper.js so that it doesn't insert newly created in the scene by default. You have to set `paper.settings.insertItems = false` when initializing your app (see the [documentation](http://paperjs.org/reference/paperscope/#settings)).

If you want some items to be part of the scene and other not, you can have a finer control over whether they are inserted or not by passing an `insert: true/false` parameter to the constructor.
Here is a sketch demonstrating this behavior.

```js
// Switch this to true to see the difference.
const INSERT = false;

const circle = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'orange',
    insert: INSERT
})
```

Comment: Also, does `import {Path} from 'paper'` import a type or a function? Because `Path.clone() as Path` returns an error: `TS2749: 'Path' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.`

Comment: In order to add the item to the scene later, you just have to add it as a child of another item which is part of the scene (the active layer for example `paper.project.activeLayer.addChild(item)`). About  `import {Path} from 'paper;'`, I would advise using `import * as paper from 'paper';` instead as I am not sure that Paper.js is fully compatible with ES6 imports.